# How can I find place address using google place search API

Tags: google-maps

Using google place search API, I am able to find place name as shown below. However I am not able to get the address of the place.

```
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
    alert(place.name);
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Google Place API and have the Server key for that, you can request the data from the API as follows:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

Where the "place_id" is the parameter which is responsible for fetching out the details of that particular place. The output is in form of JSON/XML consisting of long name, short name, phone number, time, address, URL etc. You can parse the address and displace in your website/app.

For more details click this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details)

JSON format:

```
{
"html_attributions" : [],
"result" : {
  "address_components" : [
     {
        "long_name" : "48",
        "short_name" : "48",
        "types" : [ "street_number" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Pirrama Road",
        "short_name" : "Pirrama Road",
        "types" : [ "route" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Pyrmont",
        "short_name" : "Pyrmont",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "NSW",
        "short_name" : "NSW",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "AU",
        "short_name" : "AU",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "2009",
        "short_name" : "2009",
        "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
     }
  ],
  "events" : [
    {
      "event_id" : "9lJ_jK1GfhX",
      "start_time" : 1293865200,
      "summary" : "<p>A visit from author John Doe, who will read from his latest book.</p>
                   <p>A limited number of signed copies will be available.</p>",
      "url" : "http://www.example.com/john_doe_visit.html"
    }
  ],
  "formatted_address" : "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont NSW, Australia",
  "formatted_phone_number" : "(02) 9374 4000",
  "geometry" : {
     "location" : {
       "lat" : -33.8669710,
       "lng" : 151.1958750
     }
  },
  "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
  "id" : "4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7",
  "international_phone_number" : "+61 2 9374 4000",
  "name" : "Google Sydney",
  "place_id" : "ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4",
  "scope" : "GOOGLE",
  "alt_ids" : [
     {
        "place_id" : "D9iJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
        "scope" : "APP"
     }
  ],
  "rating" : 4.70,
  "reference" : "CnRsAAAA98C4wD-VFvzGq-KHVEFhlHuy1TD1W6UYZw7KjuvfVsKMRZkbCVBVDxXFOOCM108n9PuJMJxeAxix3WB6B16c1p2bY1ZQyOrcu1d9247xQhUmPgYjN37JMo5QBsWipTsnoIZA9yAzA-0pnxFM6yAcDhIQbU0z05f3xD3m9NQnhEDjvBoUw-BdcocVpXzKFcnMXUpf-nkyF1w",
  "reviews" : [
     {
        "aspects" : [
           {
              "rating" : 3,
              "type" : "quality"
           }
        ],
        "author_name" : "Simon Bengtsson",
        "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/104675092887960962573",
        "language" : "en",
        "rating" : 5,
        "text" : "Just went inside to have a look at Google. Amazing.",
        "time" : 1338440552869
     },
     {
       "aspects" : [
          {
             "rating" : 3,
             "type" : "quality"
          }
         ],
        "author_name" : "Felix Rauch Valenti",
        "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/103291556674373289857",
        "language" : "en",
        "rating" : 5,
        "text" : "Best place to work :-)",
        "time" : 1338411244325
     },
     {
       "aspects" : [
          {
             "rating" : 3,
             "type" : "quality"
          }
         ],
        "author_name" : "Chris",
        "language" : "en",
        "rating" : 5,
        "text" : "Great place to work, always lots of free food!",
        "time" : 1330467089039
     }
  ],
  "types" : [ "establishment" ],
  "url" : "http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=10281119596374313554",
  "vicinity" : "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont",
  "website" : "http://www.google.com.au/"
 },
 "status" : "OK"
 }
```

Hope this would help!!